# weka detailed accuracy by class

Tags: weka, clique-problem

It the first time to deal with weka and ML. it's hard for me to read (detailed accuracy by class). Can anyone help me, please?
If you have any link or resources may help me.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I did an annotation of J48 output when I taught a predictive analytics class a couple of years ago. This will answer many of your questions (probably not all!).

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ssst947s2nntqyu/Annotated%20J48%20output.docx?dl=0